# Android Error code -3 when initializing Visualizer

Tags: android, visualizer

Got this error while initializing `Visualizer`

```
visualizer = new Visualizer(mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId()); <----
```

> Error: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -3
>                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -3

**NB : This is only happening in Marshmallow**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Got the cause of the problem !!!**

This is caused for dynamic permission problem for Marshmallow.

It requires `RECORD_AUDIO` permission to initialize it.

I need to give permission `Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO` before initialize the visualizer.